# PiranhaCMS: manager language after publishing

Tags: localization, piranha-cms

My problem is the following. Locally, the Piranha manager's language is correct. But after the publication - english. What's wrong? Maybe it's nececcary to explicitly set the language of the manager? But how?

Answer (score 2):

The question is closed. The solution was to explicitly specify the culture of the current thread.

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```